# How to create javax.crypto.SecretKey based on password and salt

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am not a security expert.

I have a requirement to generate `javax.crypto.SecretKey` based on `password` and `salt`.

In the existing code, we already have logic to generate `javax.crypto.SecretKey` but not based on `password and` salt`.

Also, in the existing code we already encrypt and decrypt using the `javax.crypto.SecretKey`.
There is already lot of data in DB which is encrypted using existing encrypt code and I dont think I can change existing encrypt and decrypt logic.

I am getting below the error when I try to decrypt data using the key generated based on `password` and `salt` with existing decrypt code.

```
key.getAlgorithm(): DESede
encryptedData: [B@31dc339b
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DESedeCipher.java:294)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
    at com.arjun.mytest.PMAdminKeyTest.main(PMAdminKeyTest.java:41)
```

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class PMAdminKeyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Requirement is to generate Key based on password and salt
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), "salt".getBytes(), 65536, 192);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded(), "DESede");

        System.out.println("key.getAlgorithm(): " + key.getAlgorithm());

        byte[] data = "12345678".getBytes("UTF8");

        // Existing encrypt and decrypt code. There is already lot of data in DB
        // encrypted in this manner. I dont think I can change this code.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm() + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

        System.out.println("encryptedData: " + encryptedData.toString());

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

        System.out.println("decryptedData: " + decryptedData.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: You might as well toss this out. ECB is not secure, nor is DES. This is encryption any script kiddie can break in 5 seconds. You're going to have to figure out a way to transition this crypto - perhaps as users log in, recrypt it properly. For example with Aes256 in GCM is good, possibly just Aes256 in CBC mode. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and scroll down to the penguin to see why ECB means you're screwed here. Triple DES (DESede) is slow as heck and no longer standard in any way. It may not be all that easy to hack, but, just.. update it.

Comment: @rzwitserloot: compared to PBKDF2 the slowness of TDEA is negligible, and it is still in FIPS 140 (annex A for 140-2 and SP800-140C for 140-3), IPSEC, SSH2, and TLSv1.2 (and below, but those are widely deprecated); technically 1.3 obsoleted 1.2 but according to ssllabs (Qualys) over 40% of 'most popular' websites don't implement 1.3 yet.

Comment: It's obsolete. And I noticed, @dave_thompson_085, you skipped over the ECB part. If you're going to re-encrypt this to get around the ECB part, not also updating DESede is horrible, horrible advice. I'm not sure why you're trying to score a pedantic point. It's at the cost of OP, I think, you're making it sound like they can leave the DESede part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not decrypting the encrypted data, you are simply trying to decrypt the original data.

Also while printing the data use UTF-8

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class PMAdminKeyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Requirement is to generate Key based on password and salt
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("password".toCharArray(), "salt".getBytes(), 65536, 192);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded(), "DESede");

        System.out.println("key.getAlgorithm(): " + key.getAlgorithm());

        byte[] data = "12345678".getBytes("UTF8");

        // Existing encrypt and decrypt code. There is already lot of data in DB
        // encrypted in this manner. I dont think I can change this code.
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm() + "/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

        System.out.println("encryptedData: " + encryptedData.toString());

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        // Notice this
        byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);

        // while printing the data use UTF-8 
        System.out.println("decryptedData: " +  new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was really stupid not to find it myself. I might have overlooked it because in the actual application code I am getting the same error and the same mistake is NOT made. I did some testing and found that we will get same error if we use different keys for encryption and decryption. I am debugging the encryption code now to send what actually is getting encrypted and with what key.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see is that you pass the unencrypted data to the Cipher in decrypt mode, which won't work. (The cipher obviously cannot decrypt data which is not encrypted without getting odd results.)
So change

```java
byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

to

```java
byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
```

Then, everything works fine.
Altough I doubt this error exists in your productive code, so if you still have problems on that one, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: ECB and DES didn't set off any warning bells?

Comment: I admit, I missed the fact that ECB is used here. I did realize the use of DESede, i.e. Triple DES. While this cipher is kinda old, it is still considered to provide acceptable security nowadays if I am not mistaken. So I did not address it.

Comment: @Jolly Thanks for the response. I was really stupid not to find it myself.
I might have overlooked it because in the actual application code.
You are right, the actual application code is correct.
I did some testing and found that we will get same error if we use different keys for encryption and decryption. I am debugging the encryption code now to send what actually is getting encrypted and with what key.